# How to calculate the mean and standard deviation of similarity matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, similarity

I am working with CSV files and I have a code that calculates the similarity between the documents. Post [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56509784/how-to-calculate-the-similarity-measure-of-text-document/56510765?noredirect=1#comment99619469_56510765) provide the code and details of data and output is as follow:

The data.csv looks as:

```
idx         messages
112  I have a car and it is blue
114  I have a bike and it is red
115  I don't have any car
117  I don't have any bike
```

The output is:

```
    id     112    114    115    117
    id                             
    112  100.0   78.0   51.0   50.0
    114   78.0  100.0   47.0   54.0
    115   51.0   47.0  100.0   83.0
    117   50.0   54.0   83.0  100.0
```

Now I would like to calculate the mean and standard deviation of the lower triangular of the similarity matrix (since both upper and lower are similar) without the identity data (100.0).

I tried to use the panda built-in mean and std as:

```
df_std = df.std()
df_Mean = df.mean()
```

But this considers all the data in the output like identity and upper triangular.

I would like to know if there is any way that I can calculate the mean and standard deviation the way that I mentioned.

Comment: what is your expected output

Answer (score 2):

Use `numpy.tril` with `k=-1` and make 0s `np.nan`:

```
import numpy as np

ltri = np.tril(df.values, -1)
ltri = ltri[np.nonzero(ltri)]
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [78.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [51., 47.,  0.,  0.],
       [50., 54., 83.,  0.]])
```

And now you can do `ltri.std()`, `ltri.mean()`:

```
ltri.std(), ltri.mean()
# (14.361406616345072, 60.5)
```

Comment: thanks for the comment and code. I will appreciate it in advance. I have one question as well. Now the code is ready one CSV file and performing similarity between each idx. How I can perform the same similarity between 2 different documents?

Comment: @Bilgin Updated about the zeros. For your the question in your comment, I suggest you either edit the current question or post another question (recommended) with some examples :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with mask all of the unwanted value as `np.nan`

```
df.values[np.triu_indices_from(df.values,0)]=np.nan
df.mean()
112    59.666667
114    50.500000
115    83.000000
117          NaN
dtype: float64
df.std()
112    15.885003
114     4.949747
115          NaN
117          NaN
dtype: float64
```

---

After mask the value

```
df
      112   114   115  117
112   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
114  78.0   NaN   NaN  NaN
115  51.0  47.0   NaN  NaN
117  50.0  54.0  83.0  NaN
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. How the entire upper or lower mean of triangular can be calculated. does it like an example``` df.mean(df.mean())``` ?